# Android: Relationship between small screen sizes and LDPI Resource Bucket

Tags: android, resources, screen-size, buckets

In my app, I have the following in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Now, in my Resource Bucket folders, (XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI & LDPI) I have provided copies of all the graphic resources scaled accordingly.

My question is, going on what I have, do I *need* to provide any resources in LDPI?  I mean, as I'm not supporting *small screens*, does it follow that I no longer need to provide LDPI resources or are there medium screens out there that could still look to the LDPI bucket?

I'm asking because if I don't need these, I'd rather remove them as they're pushing my APK size up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the [Dashboard about screen](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) size vs density (statistic fro, google play). You can see that the small screen is only use for ldpi. Also still up to these stats, you can can have old tablet with a large screen, but android will scale down mdpi to any ldpi device so don't worry, you can remove your ldpi resources.